# iPhone crash reports not found

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

i am trying to debug an Application I am developing using mono touch, but when I try to access Crash Reports in Xcode Organizer, I can't find any (and I know the app crashed at least 10 times).
I only see 5 files which process name is "Unknown".
I tried to locate the crash reports in

> ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice

But even there I couldn't find the reports.

Any ideas what Im missing?

Thanks!

Comment: you better try to check with break points, may be you can get something fruitful.

Comment: Unfortunately break points can't help me in this scenario, I need the crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me before when I was trying to look at persistent connection logs, maybe it will be helpful to you. It turned out I was looking at /Library/Logs instead of ~/Library/Logs, the latter library folder is not visible but the former is.

I will suggest you to try and locate them in "Console" application and it shows hidden files by default. If Console cannot find them there should be a problem with logging.